# Mouse cursor moves and applications are opening automatically

Tags: networking, security, mouse

I'm not sure what exactly happened but I've noticed that at first one user complained about his surface where just the mouse pointer started moving while programs are just opening and doing on its own. I thought it maybe a network compromise and tried removing the network cable just to cut off if there's any threats and also removed the external connected USB mouse/keyboard devices. But the problem didn't go through as it still started doing on its own. Later one more user complained the same and it was the same. Now today one user said exactly the same where I was not in place to check.

For all those users in common, we have Symantec endpoint protection in place and further my pfsense firwall has plenty of rules for incoming/outgoing along with all the port blocking... etc. I'm still confused why is this happening. Can it be a compromise or some sort of a malware? Because, I didn't find such activities when doing a full scan on those effected computers. I've even tried a `netstat -a` command to see if there's any suspicious connectivity happening on the effected PC at that event.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to run full scan with the help of Symantec Threat analysis tool.

How to run the Threat Analysis Scan in Symantec Help (SymHelp)

http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH215519

Also see if there any suspicious file present on the system, if yes submit it to symantec for further analysis.

How to Use the Web Submission Process to Submit Suspicious Files

http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH102419

Regards,
Chetan